# Restricting user's push commands privileges

Tags: git, github, branch, githooks

How can I not allow the users to make pushes that are going to create a new branch in remote repository?
And is there anyway not to let the user push to a certain remote branch in github ,e.g restrict him/her from pushing to the origin/master branch? ( Considering the account is not an organization account. I was used to do this using gitolite, but since it's github , i don't seem to know how's that done )

Answer (score 2):

You can't run custom scripts on github. That would allow malicious users to compromise their servers. If you want this restriction to help them, then you can have them use a local git hook. If you want this restriction to be absolute because of security concerns, then you can't have them push to github.